# How can you compare Cox regression models and rank them in terms of "prognostic significance"?

Tags: cox-model

How can you compare different Cox regression models to see which one provides the sharpest prognostic information?

I have a deep learning algorithm and more than 100 doctors diagnosing a disease as present or absent. I am presenting the univariate Cox regression models for the first 20 here

[image]

I have ranked these in descending order based on hazards ratio. This I am guessing is not correct - what I am trying to achieve is a ranking to see where the algorithm places among these doctors. Alternatively, I would like to show that there is no statistical difference between the top performing doctor and the algorithm. But how can I tell who is the top performing doctor as the HR, p values, and intervals all seem to come into play. Is there one metric that can be used to rank these?

Comment: I assume each model predicts the disease status or severity on the same data?

Comment: Correct. Each model is a univariate cox regression model on the same data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rank the HRs, as you have already done. In order to determine whether `doctor 4` performs as well as `algorithm`, compare the AIC or log likelihood from their respective models.

In order to determine performance of one entity relative to any other, you need to determine, *a priori*, what effect difference constitutes superiority or inferiority and set up the appropriate inference for that test. Looking at your HRs and CIs, the lowest ranked doctor’s mean effect is still within the 95% CI of the best doctor, suggesting no clinically important difference over the range of predictors (`doctors` or `algorithm`).

Comment: One question: for the remaining 80 doctors after these, would it be correct the find at what point the hr falls out of the CI and use that as a threshold above which HR are essentially equivalent?

Comment: You can, but this should all be done very much a priori, as you have a clear continuum of doctor effect. You will need to carefully pick the HR and boundaries of the HR that define a sufficient effect.

Answer (score 0):

would Harrell's c-statistic be useful here ? That assesses the ability of a predictor to distinguish those with long and short survival times - it is automatically calculated by coxph within T